# TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

He estado tratando de mostrar una lista de tareas en React, para ello dividí las tareas en dos componentes, uno que contiene cada tarea (Task) y otro que se encarga de recorrer cada tarea(Tasks). Luego paso Tasks a App.js, en teoría no es complicado pero sigo teniendo el error TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined. Los archivos son los siguientes:

Componente Task.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; 
 
class Task extends Component {
    render() {
        return <div>
                {this.props.t.title} - {this.props.t.description}
                <input type="checkbox"/>
                <button>
                    Do Somthing
                </button>
        </div>
            
    }
}

export default Task;
```

Componente Tasks.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


import Task from './Task';


class Tasks extends Component {
    render() {
        return this.props.tasks.map(t => <Task task={t} key={t.id} />)
    }
}

export default Tasks;
```

Y por último así me quedó App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

import tasks from './sample/tasks.json';

import Tasks from './components/Tasks';


class App extends Component {
  state = {
    tasks: tasks
  }
  render() {
    return <div>
      <Tasks tasks={this.state.tasks}/> 
    </div>
      
  }
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que el nombre la propiedad es incorrecta.
En el componente Tasks, cuando mapeas los elementos del json, a su componente hijo, Task, le estas pasando una propiedad con nombre task. No con nombre t.

Mi solución sería:

En el componente Task cambiar t por task.

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react'; 
 
class Task extends Component {
    render() {
        return <div>
                {this.props.task.title} - {this.props.task.description}
                <input type="checkbox"/>
                <button>
                    Do Somthing
                </button>
        </div>
            
    }
}

export default Task;
```

O más bien, puedes ambiar en el componente Tasks cuando pasamos la propiedad cambiar el nombre de task por t:

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';


import Task from './Task';


class Tasks extends Component {
    render() {
        return this.props.tasks.map(t => <Task t={t} key={t.id} />)
    }
}

export default Tasks;
```

Intentá una de las dos.

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Pude solucionar el problema de esa forma, un pequeño error que pasé por alto. Gracias